# Should I mention work done for the company which was outsourced and client had probably signed NDA with the company

Tags: professionalism, recruitment

So, I worked in company where a lot of outsourced work comes and many of the clients which are mostly devs/contractors who have taken contracts and not familiar with the technology, hence the NDA.

Should I mention the work done for the company on a recruitment portal?

It is really important as most of the work done is of same manner and I would not have anything left to mention in projects column.

Note that most of the people look for live/ features which can looked up, so if you are mentioning redactions than keep that in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NDA's usually cover the content (i.e.program code, images etc.) of the work.
In those cases you may divulge the information that you worked for company X on tool or project Y but you may not show any code examples or possibly even screenshots of the UI.

However there are also those NDA's that prohibit you from sharing the information that you worked for company X as well as any projects you worked on.
Those contracts usually are paid more because you can't name them as experience to get new work.

**So carefully read your NDA !** 
 If possible have a lawyer explain what you can and what you can't publish about the work you did.

Comment: Yes, but even with such NDAs you can say things like "Worked on a tool to optimize the widget ordering process for a major, international widget fabricator"

Comment: good point, very true. Just have to carefully dance around identifying the company and / or project. I actuall had NDA's where certain words, names and descriptions were explicitly prohibited to use. Also, big companies don't want their trademarks or IP being namedropped, especially in a manner that may seem like endorsement. It can be a real minefield sometimes but if the money or the experience is good, it's worth to be the unsung hero...(;

Answer (score 1):

From your title:

> client had probably signed NDA with the company

If the Company signed an NDA, and you didn't, you can't be bound by the NDA.

Most of the time an NDA covers the specific of the situation. They cover the code, and the algorithm. Sometimes the NDA does limit your ability to disclose the technology used.

Sometimes the  NDA covers the relationship. They say the fact that you and your company provided services to the client is protected.

In any case if you don't know about the NDA you can't be responsible for violating it.

Regardless of an NDA you do have to respect ownership of the code. So you are still restricted in what you show. You can't steal a copy of their code, and put it on a share site. That would not be allowed. But mentioning that you used technology X to solve Y for a contract with company Z, that is OK.